# How do I achieve this CV look?

Tags: cv, small-caps, resume, underline

I'm trying to replicate this CV style (below). I have some idea how to approach it, but I don't know how to achieve:

- Underline below the text
- Writing text left and right on the same line

If anyone can recommend any packages or even templates that resemble this look, I'd really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: Just a quick comment: Do yourself a favor and use one of the specialized CV classes … https://ctan.org/search?phrase=vitae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need any packages for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\noindent\textbf{\huge Jose Javier Gonzalez Ortiz}\hfill {\huge Curriculum Vitae}\vskip5pt
\hrule width \linewidth height 2pt\vskip10pt

\noindent Massachusetts Institute of Technology, \hfill josejg.com

\noindent Computer Science and Artificial Intelligence Laboratory\hfill josejg@mit.edu\vskip10pt

\noindent\textbf{\textsc{\Large Education}}\vskip5pt
\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt\vskip10pt

\noindent\textbf{Massachusetts Institute of Technology}\hfill 2019-2023 (Expected)

Ph.D. Electrical Engineering and Computer Science

Advisor: John Guttag\vskip10pt 

\noindent\textbf{Massachusetts Institute of Technology}\hfill 2017-2019

M.Sc. Electrical Engineering and Computer Science (GPA: 5.00/5.00) 

Thesis: Learning from Few Subjects with Large Amounts of Voice Monitoring Data

Courses: Machine Learning, Computer Vision, Distributed Systems, Computer Systems Security\vskip10pt 

\noindent\textbf{Universidad Pontificia Comillas}\hfill 2012-2016 

B.Sc. Telematics Engineering, (GPA: 9.95/10.00, Summa Cum Laude)

Thesis: A Simple Power Analysis Attack on the TwoFish Key Schedule\vskip10pt 

\noindent\textbf{University of Michigan, Ann Arbor}\hfill 2015-2016 

Exchange program in Computer Science (GPA: 3.94/4.00) 

Key Courses: Cryptography, Parallel Computing, Entrepreneurship, Information Retrieval\vskip10pt

\noindent\textbf{\textsc{\Large Research AND Work Experience}}\vskip5pt
\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt\vskip10pt

\noindent\textbf{Facebook AI Research, Montreal}, Research Intern\hfill 2020 

\begin{itemize}
\item Led a project analyzing distributed training of DNNs, with an emphasis on improving generalization performance \& reducing communication.
\item Carried out experiments to identify the synchronization trade-off when training networks in a data parallel
\end{itemize}

\noindent\textbf{CERN Openlab, Geneva}, Software Engineering Intern\hfill 2017 

\begin{itemize}
\item Developed C$++$ software to store and access genomic data using ROOT big data framework. 
\item Benchmarked the tools using Python and performed statistical analysis over the parameter space, improving read speed by over 15 times.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]